# How to set Mapkit user tracking button state

Tags: swift, mapkit, userlocation, mkuserlocation, showuserlocation

I've created a map with a user tracking button on the top right corner. I was wondering how I would be able to set the state to "followWithHeadlights" by default on load so that it follows the users current position just like you would have on GPS?

**Current behaviour on load:**
[Button current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxZsH.png)

**Desired behaviour on load:**
[Button desired behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArdFW.png)

**Code snippet:**

```
func setUserTrackingButton() {

    // Mapkit tracking button
    let trackingButton: MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem.init(mapView: mapView)
    trackingButton.customView?.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.01, green:0.81, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)
    trackingButton.customView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)

    let toolBarFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) , size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    let toolbar = UIToolbar.init(frame: toolBarFrame)
    toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    toolbar.isTranslucent = true
    let flex: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    toolbar.items = [flex, trackingButton, flex]

    let origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 85, y: 60)
    let roundedSquare: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)))
    roundedSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    roundedSquare.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    roundedSquare.layer.masksToBounds = true

    roundedSquare.addSubview(toolbar)
    mapView.addSubview(roundedSquare)
}
```

**ViewDidLoad includes:**

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.followWithHeading, animated: true)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user tracking mode must be set *after* the map view has fully loaded. In `viewDidLoad` this is not the case.

You can use the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `mapViewDidFinishLoading(mapView:)` to know when the map has loaded:

```
class MyMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {        
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...
        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    // ...

    func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.followWithHeading, animated: true)
    }

    // ...

}
```